# Continue multiplying by square of each of 3 numbers until result is greater than 170,000

Tags: algorithms

Given three numbers $-500 \leq x, y, z \leq 500$, start with 1 and then continually multiply by the square of each of these numbers i.e.

$$1 * x^2 * y^2 * z^2 * x^2 * y^2 * z^2 ...$$

This process stops once we get a result exceeding 170,000.

Given x, y and z, I want to find the resulting number that is greater than 170,000 efficiently.

My attempt:

First I find the value of $x^2 * y^2 * z^2$ and call it $S$. Then I try to estimate roughly how many times this goes into 170,000 so I need to solve the following for n (S is known):

$$S^n = 170,000$$
$$n = \frac{log(170000) + 2i\pi c}{log(S)}, c \in \mathbb{Z}$$

and then I find S^n and with a maximum of 4 multiplications I can find the desired number.

Sample input: 2, 3, 5

Sample output: 810,000

Explanation: $2^2 * 3^2 * 5^2 * 2^2 * 3^2 * 5^2 * 2^2 * 3^2 * 5^2 = 810,000 > 170,000$.

My method isn't very elegant, is there a way to do this with fewer operations? This method works but requires too many operations, I am trying to reduce the number of multiplications I perform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the squares are all positive you don't need or want the $2i\pi c$ term.  The inequality is real.  You can find $\log S=2(\log |x|+\log|y|+\log|z|)$ if you want.  I think the approach is quite direct.  You need to round $n$ upward, so it would be more proper to say $n=\lceil \frac {\log (170,000)}{\log S} \rceil$.  I am not sure you can have the answer in four multiplies.  Do we know $x,y,z$ are distinct?  If one of them is zero, $n$ will be infinite.  If $x=1,y=-1,z=2$ we will have $n=9$.  You need four multiplies to get $(xyz)^2$, then using repeated squaring you need four more to get $4^9=262144$, but that is not so many.

Comment: Would it be possible to do this question without having any overflow? Since the values for x, y and z can be 500, then $(500^3)^2$ will result in integer overflow.

Comment: The log approach will give you $n$ without any overflow.  You can then find $\log S$ without overflow.  You should be able to do $\exp(\log S)$ into a float without any problem.  If $500^6$ overflows your ints you either need a longer representation or to use floats.  It fits in $64$ bit ints, just not $32$.